# ¿Se puede optimizar(reducir tiempo de ejecución y lineas) código para paginar noticias?

Tags: php, web

Estoy desarrollando un sitio web que carga muchas noticias en formato de tarjetas, he optado por hacer todo el código yo mismo, al final de la primera página se imprime una suerte de "paginacion" o números de paginas con sus correspondientes botones ademas del anterior y siguiente. La misma se genera mediante una función de php, si bien falta añadir los enlaces en cada boton, me gustaria saber si se puede optimizar, ya que me llevo muchas lineas hacerla. adjunto imagen de ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el código, la función recibe dos parámetros los cuales son `$cantpag` la cual indica la cantidad total de paginas y `$actualpag` que indica la pagina actual.

```css
/*-------------------------------PAGINACION-------------------------*/
.paginacion{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  left:25%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: left 0.5s;
}
.pag{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  margin-left: 20px;
  color:black;
  transition: background-color 0.5s,color 0.5s;
}
.pag:hover{
  background-color:rgb(255, 0, 150);
  color: white;
}
.bloquear_pag:hover{
  cursor: no-drop;
  background-color: rgb(224, 222, 222);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.actual_pag{
  background-color:rgb(255, 0, 150);
  color: white;  
}
.actual_pag:hover{
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.intermedio_pag:hover{
  background-color: rgb(224, 222, 222);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
function paginacion($actualpag, $cantpag){
  echo"<div class='paginacion'>";
  if ($actualpag == 1){             /* si la pagina actual es 1 se bloquea el boton "anterior" */ 
      echo "<a class='pag bloquear_pag' href='#'>«</a>";
  }
  else{                           /*en cambio si no es 1, el boton trabaja normalmente */
      echo "<a class='pag' href='#'>«</a>";
  }
  if ($cantpag < 6){              /*si la cantidad de paginas es menor a 6 no imprimirá los cuadros intermedios[...] */
      for ($i=1; $i <= $cantpag; $i++){
          if($actualpag == $i){   /* el boton con el numero de pagina actual toma los valores de la clase "actual_pag" */
              echo "<a class='pag actual_pag' href='#'>$i</a>";
          }
          else{
              echo "<a class='pag' href='#'>$i</a>";
          } 
      }
  }
  else{ /*si la cantidad de paginas es mayor a 5 */
        switch ($actualpag) {
          case ($actualpag < 4): /* si la pagina actual es menor a 4 */
              for ($i=1; $i < 6; $i++){
                if($actualpag == $i){
                    echo "<a class='pag actual_pag' href='#'>$i</a>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<a class='pag' href='#'>$i</a>";
                }
              }
              echo"<span class='pag intermedio_pag' >...</span>";
              echo "<a class='pag' href='#'>$cantpag</a>";
              break;
          case ($actualpag > ($cantpag - 3)):
              echo "<a class='pag' href='#'>1</a>";
              echo"<span class='pag intermedio_pag' >...</span>";
              for($i=($cantpag - 4); $i <= $cantpag; $i++ ){
                  if($actualpag == $i){   /* el boton con el numero de pagina actual toma los valores de la clase "actual_pag" */
                      echo "<a class='pag actual_pag' href='#'>$i</a>";
                  }
                  else{
                      echo "<a class='pag' href='#'>$i</a>";
                  } 
              }
              break;
          default:
              echo "<a class='pag' href='#'>1</a>";
              echo"<span class='pag intermedio_pag' >...</span>";
              echo "<a class='pag' href='#'>".($actualpag - 1)."</a>";
              echo "<a class='pag actual_pag' href='#'>".$actualpag."</a>";
              echo "<a class='pag' href='#'>".($actualpag + 1)."</a>";
              echo "<a class='pag' href='#'>".($actualpag + 2)."</a>";
              echo"<span class='pag intermedio_pag' >...</span>";
              echo "<a class='pag' href='#'>$cantpag</a>";
              break;
        }
  }
  if ($actualpag == $cantpag){
      echo "<a class='pag bloquear_pag' href='#'>»</a>";
  }
  else{
      echo "<a class='pag' href='#'>»</a>";
  }
  echo "</div>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En caso de que trabajes PHP con Laravel existen funciones perfectas para la paginación, son muy eficientes y no existen dificultad para impletarlos.

Por ejemplo, si tienes `$cards = Card::all();` puedes hacer `$cars = Cars::all()->paginate($elements)` y que `$elements` sea el número de elementos por página que quieras en tu sitio.

En la vista, solamente sería cuestión de poner en el contener donde tienes tu paginación `{{ $cards->links() }}` y aplicarle los estilos que ya tienes a los elementos que tiene `links()`.

Si es PHP puro, te recomendaría implementar Laravel si no es un sistema ya muy desarrollado.

Para PHP puro, pudieras seguir la lógica que viene [aquí](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928).

Es un tutorial muy bueno que yo he usado cuando trabajaba con PHP puro

Comment: de momento trabajo sin laravel, solo con php puro, en cuanto al tutorial es bastante completo si trabajas orientado a objetos, yo estoy mas familiarizado de forma procedimental. De igual forma cabe destacar que es muy completo el tutorial, gracias!. @Noob Dev